# fetch Azure 'Files and folders' Job status using Powershell or C#

Tags: c#, powershell, azure, backup

I have been trying to find a way to fetch the status of 'Files and folders' backup jobs that has been run on several of our customers running in AzureRM. Status can be found using manually in the AzureRm portal from: 
'Recovery Services vault' -> Jobs -> 'Backup Jobs'

using powershell does not show any Job information

```
Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault | Set-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVaultContext
Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType Windows -BackupManagementType MARS |fl
Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupJob
```

Tried using C# but has yet find a way to get the information this way either, if at all possible?

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.RecoveryServices.Backup;
var creds = new Microsoft.Azure.TokenCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, token);
IRecoveryServicesBackupManagementClient client = new RecoveryServicesBackupManagementClient(creds);
Console.WriteLine(client.Jobs.ToString());
```

any ideas?

Comment: You can check the examples for getting the list of Backup Jobs using Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupJob here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.recoveryservices.backup/get-azurermrecoveryservicesbackupjob?view=azurermps-5.6.0 

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-vms-automation#monitoring-a-backup-job.

Comment: Hi @Swikruti Bose, Get-AzureRMRecoveryservicesBackupJob only shows my 'AzureVM' backups but none of the 'MARS'

Comment: You may refer this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-client-automation#back-up-files-and-folders and see if it helps.

Comment: nothing in there either, was just powershell commands for local administration...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tried using C# but has yet find a way to get the information this way either, if at all possible?

I do a demo with [Microsoft.Azure.Management.RecoveryServices.Backup 2.1.0-preview](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.RecoveryServices.Backup/2.1.0-preview). It works correctly on my side.

How to create the auth file please refer to [auth file formats](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/blob/master/AUTH.md#auth-file-formats).

```
subscription=########-####-####-####-############
client=########-####-####-####-############
tenant=########-####-####-####-############
key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
managementURI=https\://management.core.windows.net/
baseURL=https\://management.azure.com/
authURL=https\://login.windows.net/
graphURL=https\://graph.windows.net/
```

**Demo code**

```
  var subscriptionId = "subscriptionId";
  var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromFile(@"Auth file path");
  var client = new RecoveryServicesBackupClient(credentials) {SubscriptionId = subscriptionId };
  var result = client.BackupJobs.List("vaultName", "resource Group").First();
  var workloadType = ((MabJob) result.Properties).WorkloadType;
```

[image]

Packages.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Hyak.Common" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Common" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Common.Dependencies" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.AppService.Fluent" version="1.8.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Batch.Fluent" version="1.8.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.BatchAI.Fluent" version="1.8.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Cdn.Fluent" version="1.8.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Fluent" version="1.8.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerInstance.Fluent" version="1.8.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerRegistry.Fluent" version="1.8.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerService.Fluent" version="1.8.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.CosmosDB.Fluent" version="1.8.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Dns.Fluent" version="1.8.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.EventHub.Fluent" version="1.8.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent" version="1.8.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Graph.RBAC.Fluent" version="1.8.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.KeyVault.Fluent" version="1.8.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Locks.Fluent" version="1.8.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Fluent" version="1.8.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Msi.Fluent" version="1.8.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Network.Fluent" version="1.8.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.RecoveryServices.Backup" version="2.1.0-preview" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Redis.Fluent" version="1.8.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent" version="1.8.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Search.Fluent" version="1.8.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus.Fluent" version="1.8.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.Fluent" version="1.8.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Fluent" version="1.8.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.TrafficManager.Fluent" version="1.8.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.9" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Async" version="1.0.168" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.14" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" version="2.28.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.22" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime" version="2.3.9" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure" version="3.3.10" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication" version="2.3.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Dynamic.Runtime" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Queryable" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Net.Requests" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="WindowsAzure.Storage" version="8.1.4" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, had to use the preview and then I was able to list the job status