# Reading the firewall IP list for a storage account

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, azure-storage-account

Is it possible to read the list of allowed IP range of an storage account in azure using c# code i.e storage account api

Comment: Probably yes. Did you try anything so far and have a *specific* problem?

Comment: when i try to use the storage account api i was able to retrive IP's specific to SAS using the SASToken property but i couldn't find any method or property that points to the firewall's IP Range

Comment: Do have any update about this thread?

Comment: fluent sdk is worlking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to read the list of allowed IP range of an storage account in azure using c# code i.e storage account api.

Yes, we could use [Azure Fluent SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net) to do that. About how to get auth file, please refer to another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49647116/fetch-azure-files-and-folders-job-status-using-powershell-or-c-sharp/49690311#49690311).

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core;


var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromFile(@"auth file path");
var azure = Azure
            .Configure()
            .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
            .Authenticate(credentials)
            .WithDefaultSubscription();
var account = azure.StorageAccounts.GetByResourceGroup(resoureGroup, accountName);
var ipRange = account.IPAddressRangesWithAccess;
```

Test Result:
[image]