# How to generate Security PIN from Recovery Services vault using .Net SDK?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-sdk-.net, azure-sdk

Currently I am trying with below code but getting System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'.

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.RecoveryServices.Backup;
public static ISecurityPINsOperations SecurityPINs { get; }
public static class GenerateSecurityPIN
    {
        private static readonly ISecurityPINsOperations Operations1;
        var pin = await SecurityPINs.GetAsync("rsv-itops-azure-support", "rg-azure-itops-rnd-dev");
    }
```

Referencing below  links :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.recoveryservices.backup.securitypinsoperationsextensions?view=azure-dotnet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You should install `Microsoft.Azure.Management.RecoveryServices.Backup -Version 4.1.5-preview` with below command.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Management.RecoveryServices.Backup -Version 4.1.5-preview
```

Then you sample code, should be like this, you need create `RecoveryServicesBackupClient` first.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.RecoveryServices.Backup;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var subscriptionId = "";
            var vaultname = "";
            var resourcegroup = "";
            var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromFile(@"Auth file path");
            var client = new RecoveryServicesBackupClient(credentials) { SubscriptionId = subscriptionId };
            var pin = client.SecurityPINs.GetAsync(vaultname,resourcegroup).Result.SecurityPIN;
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you don't wante to upgrade package, you also can [use restapi to get PIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/backup/securitypins/get).

Related post:

[fetch Azure 'Files and folders' Job status using Powershell or C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49647116/fetch-azure-files-and-folders-job-status-using-powershell-or-c-sharp/49690311#49690311)

Comment: Thank you very much for reply . I trying with below code:  var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory
                       .FromServicePrincipal(clientCredentials.ClientId, clientCredentials.ClientSecret, requestObject.TenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
            var client = new RecoveryServicesBackupClient(credentials) { SubscriptionId = requestObject.SubscriptionId };
            var pin = client.SecurityPINs.GetAsync(requestObject.VaultName, requestObject.ResourceGroupName);
 But getting "WaitingForActivation"   Please help me on this.

Comment: @DnyaneshSurya var pin = client.SecurityPINs.GetAsync(vaultname, resourcegroup).Result.SecurityPIN;